# Integrate keycloak with external identity provider with SAML and nodeJs

Tags: node.js, keycloak, saml

We have an use case where we have the following scenario:

- External identity provider
- Keycloak communicating with external identity provider through SAML protocol
- NodeJs and angular application to login

The goal is our login web page on angular and nodeJs to call keycloak to login the user in the external identity provider through SAML.
We need this because we need a JWT token from keycloak to authenticate the requests to our internal services.
Until now we were able to integrate keycloak and the external identity provider through SAML, the login works fine if we use the keycloak login page and select the identity provider there. Now we need to use our login page to login through keycloak (that will login through the external identity provider), but we can't find a solution for that.

Anyone can point us in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Use keycloak-js to handle it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to use keycloak-js to handle it :)